# How to install Third party Lightning components to Sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sandbox

I am trying to install the third-party lightning component to my sandbox.Below is the link

https://sites.google.com/view/flowunofficial/flow-screen-components/fsc-dynamic-question?authuser=0

When I click install, it just takes me to login.salesforce where my sandbox credentials don't work. Is there a way I could download this lightning component into my sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you land on the login page, change the URL to "test.salesforce.com":

```
https://test.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04tB0000000N8IW
```

This works for any package that you want to install in a Sandbox but don't have the sandbox install URL for.

Comment: Great. That works, I had a custom url for sandbox, so I replaced the login.salesforce.com with my custom url and kept the other url part same and it worked.  Thanks again.